Change Y intervals from 25% to 10%
Everything looks good for my stacked area plot but I would like the intervals displayed on the y axis to change from 25% to 10%. It seems simple but I can't get it and any help is greatly appreciated.
Code:
ggplot(data3_long, 
    aes(x = fyear, 
        y = percentage, 
        fill = factor(variable, 
          levels = c("CHE", "IVAO", "ACO", "RECT", "AO", "INTAN", "PPENT")), 
        group = variable)) + 
  geom_area(position = 'stack') + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_palette, name = NULL) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Percentage", labels = scales::percent_format()) + 
  labs(x = "Year", title = "Test") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1))

I tried adding breaks and it didn't work:
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, by=10), limits=c(0,100))
Accuracy didn't work either but I did not expect it to. Thanks again.



Where are you adding your new scale_y_continuous? Are you replacing the one that's already there? 2) Is data3_long$percentage actually between 0 and 100 or between 0 and 1?


100% is 1 so you probably mean scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, by=0.1), limits=c(0,1))

One can use the breaks argument in scale_y_continuous with percentages as fractions of 1.0. As the example missed a reproducible data set, I create some simple test data:
library(ggplot2)

## a reproducible data set
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:10,
  y = runif(30),
  g = factor(rep(1:3, each = 10))
)

## simplified plot, concentrating on the necessary parts
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=g)) + 
  geom_area(position='stack') +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Percentage", 
                     labels = scales::percent_format(), 
                     breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1))


tpetzoldt's answer did it. I think when I was trying to add breaks using a 0 - 100 scale it didn't work because data3_long$percentage is 0-1. Or maybe I was doing something else wrong. This worked in any case, many thanks!
